# Why does LLDB does not acknowledge complete selector name as a breakpoint?

Tags: selector, breakpoints, lldb

I have a function name declared as follows in OBjective C :

```
- (void)placeViews:(CGSize)screenSize;
```

In my viewDidLoad i call this function, and I want to put a breakpoint when it is called as such:

```
[self placeViews:size]
```

So in LLDB I am entering the following breakpoint command:

```
breakpoint set --selector placeViews:screenSize
```

But the LLDB is unable to resolve the breakpoint

However, when I only use "placeViews:" as the selector it finds the selector and adds the breakpoint.
What I don't get is why it finds the selector when I use "placeViews:", but it doesn't find it when i used the entire method name "placeViews:screenSize".
Why is that? 
So what happens when I have multiple methods like another one such as "placeViews:screenSize:oneMoreThing" and I want to set a breakpoint only on this method, how can LLDB distinguish between "placeViews:screenSize" and "placeViews:screenSize:oneMoreThing" ?

thank you!

-Malena

Answer (score 0):

placeViews:screenSize is not the selector name, the selector is just "placeViews:".  The selector name does not include the variable name that is passed to the message that that selector indicates (screenSize in your case.)

That actually makes sense if you think about it, because users have to provide the "placeViews:" part of the selector when they call the method, but "screenSize" has no part of how they call it.  Also, it is NOT an error to use screenSize in your @interface and a completely different name in the @implementation.  So it really shouldn't be part of the name the runtime conses up for the message.

You can verify this, for instance run this in Terminal

$ otool -o  | grep placeViews
              name 0x100000f56 placeViews:

No mention of screenSize.